# .so files in python

Tags: python, function, binary

I am trying to modify a program.
I see function calls that go into a file called myProgLib.so 
Its a binary file but I want to know what happens in these functions that are being called, is there a way to do this? I need to understand them before I can modify them to my needs

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Read the source code of the library.

Comment: Sorry but in the list of files I cannot see a "source file"

Comment: Plus if it's compiled with debug symbols you can `gdb`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I was told by my boss that the source file does not exist for this one, I guess I cannot see it.

Comment: @rohithah - Ignatio is being *ahem* direct in answering, but if it's compiled and you don't have the source files used to compile it (and optionally if the library isn't compiled with debug symbols) you're out of luck. You could reverse-engineer the binary but I think that will be a bit too much hassle.

Comment: Thank you Joe for your patient and descriptive answer.

Comment: You can use `gdb` even if it is compiled without debugging symbols, actually.

Comment: And one more important thing. If you don't have source of this library, it is very likely that you'll do something illegal trying to understand what happpens inside.